# KineticJS - Kinetic.Path setFill - slow animation required

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have an image from Kinetic.Path objects and every area can be filled with mouse click - setFill(...).

Is it possible to fill an area with "slow animation"? Like there - http://goo.gl/0rgry .

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, could you make a jsfiddle so your code could be played around with? This makes for more accurate results.

Second, there is an answer, Transitions.

Most things in KineticJS can be transitioned from one configuration to another.

```
  var path = new Kinetic.Path({fill: 'blue'});
```

then:

```
  path.transitionTo({fill: 'red', duration: 2};
```

duration is what controls the speed. I don't know how colors get transitioned so you should look up 'shape tango' on the kineticJS site.